# Firefox: Identify CPU hungry tabs

Tags: firefox

I run Firefox with many tabs open. After a while the process 'Web Content' eats up all CPU. `top` looks like:

```
  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                   
 4781 tange     29   9 8887164 5.451g 711344 R 100.7 17.4   1830:49 Web Content               
 4727 tange     29   9 11.926g 2.788g 416572 R  83.1  8.9   2732:53 Web Content               
 4802 tange     20   0 12.123g 3.492g 669688 R  64.2 11.2   1324:58 Web Content               
 4666 tange     20   0 7536424 3.414g 635220 S  36.8 10.9 887:56.67 Web Content
```

How can I tell/kill the tabs, that are causing this without affecting any other tabs?

Comment: Have you taken a look at `about:performance` within Firefox ?  A similar question was asked on superuser.com, at https://superuser.com/questions/234923/determine-which-tab-in-firefox-is-using-cpu-resources